# How to turn the equations of motion into horizontal and vertical positions of the mass as functions of time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, harmonic-oscillator, projectile

We were given this physics problem:

Let $z(t) = y(t) + \alpha$ and
recall the Simple Harmonic Motion Position Equation $x(t) = Acos(\omega t + \phi)$.

From the equations of motion, one can show that the horizontal and vertical positions of the mass as functions of time can be written as:

\begin{align*}
x(t) &= Acos(\omega t) + Bsin(\omega t)\\
y(t) &= Ccos(\omega t) + Dsin(\omega t) + E
\end{align*}

provided that the coefficients satisfy the following conditions:

\begin{align*}
x(0) = y(0) &= 0\\
v_x(t=0) &= v_0cos\ \theta\\
v_y(t = 0) &= v_0sin\ \theta
\end{align*}

Determine the coefficients $A, B, C, D,$ and $E$ in terms of the given variables.

I was able to identify $A$ and $B$, I am having a hard time identifying the rest. Here is my approach:

(Horizontal)
Plugging in what we know:

\begin{align*}
x(0) = Acos(0) + Bsin(0) = 0\\
Acos(0) = 0\\
A = 0
\end{align*}

When $A = 0$, $x(t) = Bsin(\omega t)$

In solving for B, take note that $v_x(t=0) = v_0cos\ \theta$. To get $v_x$ from $x(t)$, we get the first derivative of $x(t) = Acos(\omega t) + Bsin(\omega t)$ with respect to time. We get:

\begin{align*}
v_x &= -\omega Asin\ \omega t + \omega Bcos\ \omega t\\
v_x &= -\omega Asin\ 0 + \omega Bcos\ \omega t\\
v_x &= -\omega A(0) + \omega Bcos\ \omega t\\
v_x &= \omega Bcos\ \omega t
\end{align*}

Now we plug in what we know:
\begin{align*}
    v_x(t = 0) = \omega B\ cos(0) &= v_0\ cos\ \theta\\
    \omega B &= v_0\ cos\ \theta\\
    B &= \dfrac{v_0\ cos\ \theta}{\omega}
\end{align*}
Going back to our equation $x(t) = B\ sin\ \omega t$.

Since $B = \dfrac{v_0\ cos\ \theta}{\omega}$, we get the horizontal position-time function:
\begin{gather*}
    x(t) = \dfrac{v_0cos\ \theta}{\omega}sin\ \omega t
\end{gather*}

I wish to know if my answer is right, and also how to look for the remaining 3 variables.

Comment: Can you check that $x(t)$ you found satisfies the initial conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the values you got for $A$ and $B$ are correct, you should plug your solution into the equations defining the initial conditions for $x(t)$ and see if they are satisfied.

To get solutions for the remaining variables, take note that you still have initial conditions for $y(t)$.